# jquery each function is not working inside the $.ajax() success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load, each

I am having a comment sscript on a page which is containing one main question and their answers just like stack over flow. 
For each answer there is a comment script also. on load of the question page the each answer load the comments with the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.disagree_comments').each(function(){
    $(this).load("includes/disagree_comments_loader.php?aid="+$(this).parents('.answer_text').children('.agree_disagree_main_cont').children('#answer_id').val());
   });
});
```

But when i do the same thing on ajax success it is not working am i doing something wrong or is there a different methos to do this?

```
 $('#comment_save').click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'includes/reply_editor.php', 
        data: "comment="+$('#comment_text_update').val()+"&id="+$('#commentid_edit').val(),
        success: function(){
            $('#comment_text_update').val('');
            $('#commentid_edit').val('');
            $('.comment_edit_transparent_layer').css('display','none');


                $('.disagree_comments').each(function(){
                    $(this).load("includes/disagree_comments_loader.php?aid="+$(this).parents('.answer_text').children('.agree_disagree_main_cont').children('#answer_id').val());
                });

        }
    });


});
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working

Comment: is the success method getting called

Comment: The fact that `#answer_id` is in your `.each()` loop makes me think that there is more than one element with an `id` of `answer_id`, right? If so, then that's your problem.

Comment: when i edit the comment using #comment_save its saving the comment but not loading the all comments again which its loading with each() function

Comment: @Blender - hmmm may be this is the problem let me check

Comment: No there are different answer and each answer carrier containing its different #anwer_id, so with that it should call the comments of each answer carrier

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: @ArunPJohny - shared the html, a little complicated :)

Comment: oh guys i found actually i am not targetting the right div. the right div is  .answer_agree_disagree_review

Answer (score 0):

```
data: "comment="+$('#comment_text_update').val()+"&id="+$('#commentid_edit').val(),
```

should be

```
data: {comment:$('#comment_text_update').val(),id:$('#commentid_edit').val()},
```

Comment: actually the data is working its saving also, the thing is not working is the each function. Its not loading again the comments of each .disagree_comments element.

Answer (score 0):

Targetting on wrong div $(.disagree_comment) the right one was $('.answer_agree_disagree_review')

Modify code:

```
$('#comment_save').click(function(){

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'includes/reply_editor.php', 
    data: "comment="+$('#comment_text_update').val()+"&id="+$('#commentid_edit').val(),
    success: function(){
        $('#comment_text_update').val('');
        $('#commentid_edit').val('');
        $('.comment_edit_transparent_layer').css('display','none');


           $('.answer_agree_disagree_review').each(function(){
                        $(this).load("includes/answer_reply_loader.php?aid="+$(this).parents('.answer_text').children('.agree_disagree_main_cont').children('#answer_id').val());
                });
            });

    }
});


});
```